# Saving XML file with Joomla module

Tags: xml, joomla, domdocument, joomla3.0

I am searching for a while but I haven't foung a single word about it. I am developing a Joomla module which will save a batch of XML files based on database data. It works fine until the most important moment - saving.

A have this in my code:

```
$doc->save("files".$DB_id.".xml");
```

And it just simply don't work. I woudl like to save those generated files to a speciall folder somewhere, but I don't even know how to save it to the root folder of module. Is it even possible? And how can I do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the module-file root with a simple echo in the file itself:

```
<?= __FILE__ ?>
```

Then you get the server-root of the file and you are able to use this returned string to save files to this path.

Comment: oh i forgot, i use this often and dont remember the echo way :D ..for this purpose just do <?php echo __FILE__ ?>